# execute php script inside shell script?

Tags: php, shell

I want to call a php script inside shell script and need to send 4 parameters.I called that called that inside shellscript like this.

```
php /var/www/php/myscript.php $var1 $var2 $var3 $var4
```

but php script didn't execute. so what is the correct way to send parameters to php script and execute script inside shellscript?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an executable file `file.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

include('your/file.php');
exit;
```

or with the current environment

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

include('your/file.php');
exit;
```

Then execute it on the command line with

```
$ ./file.sh
```

Comment: Dont forget to add the right permissions to the file if you want to execute it by issue "./file.sh"

for example 
chmod +x file.sh

Answer (score 0):

This is sample, pay special attention to the quotes in the parameters to wrap any character in the string like spaces or dashes that can affect the args reading.

bash.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
php test.php "$1" "$2"
```

test.php

```
<?php

$a = $argv[1];
$b = $argv[2];

echo "arg1 : $a, arg2: $b";
```

Some Outputs

```
$bash bash.sh Hello World
arg1 : Hello, arg2: World

$bash bash.sh Hello
arg1 : Hello, arg2:

$bash bash.sh "Hello World"
arg1 : Hello World, arg2:
```

Hope this helps